# Unable to bring up IE in Selenium WebDriver Python

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer

I am using Selenium to automate the Web page test with IE11, I did all of the steps following the instruction from https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration, but still error when I run my automation, I have not been able to bring up IE browser yet.

1. (For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.)
2. Protected mode settings are the same for all zones
3. Enhanced Protected Mode is disabled.
4. Set Zoom level to 100%

But I still have not been able to bring up IE browser, I got following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_contact (__main__.IETestCases)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_ie.py", line 528, in setUp
    IEDefault.setUp(self)
  File "test_ie.py", line 88, in setUp
    self.driver = webdriver.Ie(r'C:\Users\jzhao\WebPageTest\IEDriverServer_x64_3.4.0\IEDriverServer.exe')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py", line 57, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 188, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 165, in check_response
raise exception_class(value)
WebDriverException: Message: Error 400: Bad Request
Invalid URI: [http://127.0.0.1:56761/session]
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Version:

- Selenium 3.4.3
- IE 11
- Windows 7 64-bit
- IEDriverServer_x64_3.4.0
- Python 2.7.13

Comment: Can you consider to try out an answer based on Python 3.6.1? Thanks

Comment: I have never used python, so I'm not familiar with their stack trace, but it appears that the error is complaining about the web page URL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

While working with `Selenium 3.4.0`, `IEDriverServer 3.4.0`, `IE 11` through `Python 3.6.1` bindings, you can take help of the `DesiredCapabilities` class to make a few configuration to open `IE 11` as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

cap = DesiredCapabilities().INTERNETEXPLORER
cap['platform'] = "Win8"
cap['version'] = "11"
cap['browserName'] = "internet explorer"
cap['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True
cap['nativeEvents'] = False
cap['requireWindowFocus'] = True
cap['INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS'] = True
driver=webdriver.Ie(capabilities=cap, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\IEDriverServer.exe')

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: DebanjanB: Thank you for your answer, but I am using python 2.7.13, with DesiredCapabilities, I still have trouble bring up IE 11. Is there any other way to bring up IE in python 2.7.13?

Comment: DebanjanB: I used Python 3.6.1 to try again, it did not work, I got the same error "Error 400: Bad Request Invalid URI: [http://127.0.0.1:57525/session]"